# Three.js : Invisible background for background and png particles

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm having trouble setting invisible background and alpha channel on my particles.

For christmas I wanted to use your example script `wegl_particles_sprite`. Adapted to the situation. I have set the code in a full screen div in foreground and succeeded to make it unclickable so that I can still use my website. The problem is that I couldn't set png alpha channels to transparent even with `transparent=true;`.

First I set the background transparent: OK

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { clearAlpha: 1, alpha:true } );
```

But can't load my snowflakes with alpha channels transparents. Need help someone for making my christmas magic?

Edit: Sorry was a typing error, the problem remains! for the particles ^^

Comment: Can you show a live example to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: I agree with westLangley. We need an example. Or at least an screenshot.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/ketzylcoatl/3b75p/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/ketzylcoatl/3b75p/5/), for code, [http://jsfiddle.net/ketzylcoatl/3b75p/5/embedded/result/](http://jsfiddle.net/ketzylcoatl/3b75p/5/embedded/result/) for full screen result, I couldn't load a png from far url.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt that be

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { clearAlpha: 1, alpha:true } );
```

Comment: Please explain in what way your answer differs.

Comment: This generates a runtime error:


   alpha=true 

This sets THREE.js webglrenderer to use alpha transparency


   alpha:true

Comment: Edit: Sorry was a typing error, the problem remains! for the particles ^^

Answer (score 0):

What kind of material did you use for the snowflakes? Maybe this can be useful:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_blending.html

Most likely you will need to do something like

```
material.transparent = true;
material.blending = THREE.AdditiveAlphaBlending;
```

Comment: I used the default one given `materials[i] = new THREE.ParticleSystemMaterial( { size: size, map: sprite, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, depthTest: false, transparent : true } );
materials[i].color.setHSL( color[0], color[1], color[2] );
particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem( geometry, materials[i] ); ` and also tried with THREE.AdditiveAlphaBlending; without success :-(

Comment: Besides, on your given example on: [http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_blending.html](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_blending.html) it is said: `renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { alpha: false } );` which is not my goal, I need all the background to be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have succeeded. With the code above and a png with an already invisible background, everything seems to work! As you can see on:

http://www.makedifferent.fr

take the code on [http://jsfiddle.net/ketzylcoatl/3b75p/5/] and enjoy!

Thanks anyway and Happy New Year!